Is the grading of a poset unique?

A graded poset is a poset $(P,\leq)$ with a map $\rho:P\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ where $\rho$ is strictly monotone, and if $x,y\in P$ where $y$ covers $x$, (i.e. $x\lessdot y$), then $\rho(y)=\rho(x)+1$. The map $\rho$ is called the rank function.

If $P$ is a poset, and there exists a rank function $\rho$ for $P$, is it unique (up to constant)?
The first thing to note is that this is always false when the comparability graph of $P$ is disconnected, since we can add a constant to $\rho$ for one of the equivalence classes (w.r.t. comparability). Hence, we add the following assumptions.

We assume that the comparability graph of $P$ is connected, i.e. for every two $x,y\in P$ there exist $x=z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n=y\in P$ where $z_i$ is comparable to $z_{i+1}$ for each $i$, and for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
For simplicity, we assume that the minimum of $\rho$ is always $0$.

I think I’ve worked out a proof for the finite case (see below), but the infinite case seems difficult.
I’d be very interested in seeing examples of non-unique rank functions, but even more so in finding weaker conditions for uniqueness. Wikipedia also mentions that any bounded and graded poset has a unique rank function, but this is only partially weaker than assuming finiteness, since finite posets may be unbounded.

Proof for $P$ finite
Let $P$ be a finite poset with rank functions $\rho$ and $\rho’$ as above. Let $x,y\in P$, and $x=z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n=y\in P$ where $z_i$ is comparable to $z_{i+1}$ for each $i$, and for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $P$ is finite, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $z_i$ covers $z_{i+1}$ or vice versa for each $i$ (by replacing $z_i, z_{i+1}$ by a chain of covers). Using induction we can easily see that
$$
\rho(y)-\rho(x)=\rho’(y)-\rho’(x)=|\{i\in\mathbb{N} \,\mid z_i \lessdot z_{i+1}\}| -  |\{i\in\mathbb{N} \,\mid z_{i+1} \lessdot z_i\}|.
$$
This implies that $\rho = \rho’$ on $P$ if there exists $x\in P$ such that $\rho(x)=\rho’(x)$. It also implies that $\max \rho = \max \rho’$. Suppose that $\rho(x) = 0$ and $\rho(y)=\max \rho$, then we must have $\rho’(x)=0$, so we are done.

Most of your proof doesn't require $P$ to be finite.  In fact, by my accounting, the first statement that can't be justified in the infinite case is talking about the maximum values.

I agree, but making sure the $z_i$ cover each other also requires a condition like “intervals of $P$ must be finite”.

You don't need the [bounded] intervals of $P$ to be finite (certainly, this may not be true).  You only need the bounded chains to be finite.  This is forced by the definition of "graded poset".

That’s interesting! How could we make sure the maximum is finite? I thought assuming that there are no infinite chains would work, but that’s not enough.

@BrianMoehring I posted an adapted proof. Thanks for the help! I think it's correct, but some confirmation is always welcome.

By adapting the proof for the finite case we prove that all rank functions of posets with connected comparability graphs are unique (up to a constant).

Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset with rank functions $\rho$ and $\rho'$ whose minimum is $0$. As above we assume that $P$ has a connected comparability graph. As @brianmoehring pointed out, the arguments from the finite case prove that $\rho(y)-\rho(x)=\rho'(y)-\rho'(x)$ for all $x,y\in P$. Let $x,y\in P$ such that $\rho(x)=0$ and $\rho'(y)=0$, then since $\rho(y)=-\rho'(x)$ we have that $\rho'(x)=0$. Now for any $z\in P$ we clearly have $\rho(z)=\rho'(z)$ by the above equation.
